# How to repeat dnorm in R using each value in a vector as the mean?

Tags: r, repeat, normal-distribution

I have a vector:

```
chbin <- seq (from = 0, to = 10, by = 0.02)
```

I have two other vectors each of 45 values.

```
chmean
cherr
```

I need to create a dataframe. 
Each row of the dataframe should have 45 values where the first value is `dnorm(chbin, mean = (chmean[1]), sd = (cherr[1], log=FALSE)` and the second value is `dnorm(chbin, mean = (chmean[2]), sd = (cherr[2], log=FALSE)` and so on through to `dnorm(chbin, mean = (chmean[45]), sd = (cherr[45], log=FALSE)`. i.e. for each value in the chbin the dnorm is calculated 45 times, once for each value in chmean and corresponding value in cherr. 
The resultant dataframe will have 45 columns and the same number of rows as values in chbin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following nested for-loop:

```
chbin <- seq (from = 0, to = 10, by = 0.02)
chmean <- seq (from = 1, to = 2, by = 0.02)
cherr <- seq (from = 1, to = 2, by = 0.02)

foo <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=length(chbin), ncol=length(chmean)) )

for(i in 1:length(chbin) ){
 for(j in 1:length(chmean) ){
  foo[i,j] <- dnorm(chbin[i], mean = chmean[j], sd = cherr[j], log=FALSE) 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mapply` can be used to solve the problem:

```
chbin <- seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 0.02)
chmean <- seq(from = 1, to = 2, by = 0.02)
cherr <- seq(from = 1, to = 2, by = 0.02)    

foo <- mapply(function(mean,sd) dnorm(chbin,mean,sd), mean=chmean, sd=cherr)
```